# Replace checkbox in MailEnvelop with custom value

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to send an document as email body. The document contains several `{ FORMCHECKBOX }` fields, which are either selected or not. Now, whenever I actually send the email, the checkboxes are not included at all. Because of this issue, I thougth about replacing the checkboxes with "Yes" or "No", depending on the selection.

I found this code, to replace all checkboxes, but it doesn't care for the actual selection:

```
Sub ChkBxClr()
    Dim i As Long, Rng As Range
    With ActiveDocument
        For i = .FormFields.Count To 1 Step -1
            With .FormFields(i)
                If .Type = wdFieldFormCheckBox Then
                    Set Rng = .Range
                    .Delete
                    Rng.Text = "[__]"
                End If
            End With
        Next
        Set Rng = Nothing
    End With
End Sub
```

Also this code changes the whole document and not just the email body, which I would like to prevent.

The overall code:

```
Sub SendEmail()

    Dim Subject As String
    Dim From As String

    On Error Resume Next

    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="From"
    From = Selection.Text

    Subject = "Title"

    Call ChkBxClr

    ActiveWindow.EnvelopeVisible = True
    With ActiveDocument.MailEnvelope.Item
        .To = "<some mail address>"
        .Subject = Subject
        .Send
    End With

End Sub

Sub ChkBxClr()
    Dim i As Long, Rng As Range
    With ActiveDocument
        For i = .FormFields.Count To 1 Step -1
            With .FormFields(i)
                If .Type = wdFieldFormCheckBox Then
                    Set Rng = .Range
                    .Delete
                    Rng.Text = "[__]"
                End If
            End With
        Next
        Set Rng = Nothing
    End With
End Sub
```

So the question is, how can I either display the checkboxes within the email body **or** replace the checkboxes (preferably only in message body) with a text, depending on the selection?

Comment: You can get the HTMLBODY 

And do a "Scrapping" with the HTML , 

Dim HtmlBODY as MSHTML2.HTMLBODY

Set htmlBody = OutlokMail.HTMLBody

Comment: @RonanVico Neither `MSHTML2.HTMLBODY` nor `OutlookMail.HTMLBody` exist for me

Comment: I found [this link](http://www.office-loesung.de/ftopic642319_0_0_asc.php) now which includes code to completely convert the document into HTML and send it so the recipient

Comment: Does what you found in the link solve your problem, then? Or are you still looking for help? If you're looking for help, are you sure these are form field checkboxes (just double-checking)? Not ActiveX controls or content controls? What do you mean by the first code "doesn't care for the actual selection"?

Comment: The link is the solution to this problem I had. What I mean with "doesn't care for the actual selection" is that I could only replace the checkboxes with one specific string and not change the string depending on if the checkbox is selected or not